# Using Function in JenkinsFile Parameter Description

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to add a function in JenkinsFile Declarative pipelines parameter's description but struggling to make it work.

Idea is to have a Jenkins Job specific for the environment. and would like to see the choice parameter to show environment name in the description of the variable.

My pipeline looks like this

```
def check_env = app_env(ENVS, env.JOB_NAME)

pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '20'))
        timestamps()
    }
    parameters{
string(name: 'myVariable', defaultValue: "/", description: 'Enter Path To App e.g / OR /dummy_path for ' {check_env} )
}
    stages{
        stage('Running App') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'myApp:latest'                
                }
            }
            steps{
                script{
                      sh label: 'App', script: "echo "App is running in ${check_env} "
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried multiple combinations for **check_env** e.g check_env, check_env(), ${check_env} function but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

## String Interpolation

I believe this is simply a [String Interpolation](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/automating-with-jenkinsfile/string-interpolation) issue.  Notice my use of double quotes below

```
parameters{
    string(name: 'myVariable', defaultValue: "/", description: "Enter Path To App e.g / OR /dummy_path for ${check_env}")
}
```

Your build page should then interpolate your variable

[image: build page]

> To test I simply set `def check_env = 'live'` since I do not have the code for your method